# unable to read repository when installing google plugin for eclipse

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

when I tried to install Google plugin for eclipse, the installation was always failed with the following error messages.

the first ones:

> Unable to connect to repository h**ps://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml
>   Unable to connect to repository h**ps://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml
>   Connection timed out: connect

I clicked the OK button, after a few minutes, the second ones popped up as follows.

> Unable to read repository at h**ps://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml.
>   Unable to read repository at h**ps://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2/content.xml.
>   Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Then I clicked the OK button again, the installation stopped and failed.

I totally follow the instruction on Google's official website https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started. The version of Eclipse I used is
Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno), and the direct link of the plugin for Eclipse 3.8/4.2 (Juno) is  https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2.

BTW,  the goagent was running during I did all the above searching and installation, would this be a problem of the connection failure? Hope it's not, because I need to run goagent otherwise I cannot access to Google's websites...

Could anyone tell me have to fix the problem? Thanks in advance!

PS. ** stands for tt. I made such changes because the body of my question now cannot contain more than two links...

Comment: Have you tried selecting Native connection in Proxy settings and install again?